# The request body is sent as json even though the content type is set as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

This is related to an existing spring boot question raised by me([Request Body is not properly encoded and hidden when using spring form encoder in Feign Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690353/request-body-is-not-properly-encoded-and-hidden-when-using-spring-form-encoder-i)).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923249/spring-4-requestmapping-consumes-vs-headers#:%7E:text=If%20you%20used%20consumes%3D%22application,client%20request%20is%20coming%20in), we can add either content type in headers or add during request mapping itself as consumes.

So what I did was added content type in headers in the client configuration class

```
public class EmailClientConfiguration  {
    
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor(Account<Account> account) {
        return template -> {
             template.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient client() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }
    
    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return new JacksonDecoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Encoder feignFormEncoder () {
        return new SpringFormEncoder(new JacksonEncoder());
    }
}
```

and I see in the headers the content type is correctly set as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** when the request is sent. But the request body is still sent in json format and also not hidden.

**Request Body:**

```
Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
requestBody.put("username", "xyz");
requestBody.put("email", "xyz@gmail.com");
requestBody.put("key", "xxx");
```

**Request Body received in server end:**

```
{"{\n  \"key\" : \"xxx\",\n  \"email\" : \"xyz@gmail.com\",\n  \"username\" : \"xyz\"\n}"
```

When I add consumes in my request mapping as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
@FeignClient(name = "email", url = "localhost:3000", 
    configuration = EmailClientConfiguration.class)
public interface EmailClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/email/send", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    ResponseDto sendEmail(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody);
    
}
```

it works fine(request body is hidden in server end and also properly encoded). And when I removed the header in the configuration class and adding only consumes works fine without no issues but the vice versa has this problem.

I searched in internet for this and couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feign encodes the request body and parameters before passing the request to any `RequestInterceptor` (and rightly so). If you do not declare `consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, `SprinFormEncoder` doesn't know that you're trying to send form data, so it delegates serialization to the inner `JacksonEncoder` which only does JSON (see for yourself by printing `template.body()` before setting the header).

Handling such a well-supported header in the interceptor doesn't seem like a good idea, when you already have `consumes`. If you insist on doing so, you have to provide your own encoder which doesn't rely on the header value and always outputs form-urlencoded data.